# citusdb ERROR: ERROR: cannot execute PREPARE for a distributed query plan

Tags: postgresql, citus

I'm just did the citusdb tutorial. And local using "psql" works fine. But when I try do the same query using native postgres jdbc I get the error:

```
ERROR: ERROR: cannot execute PREPARE for a distributed query plan
Query = SELECT count(*) FROM customer_reviews
```

Local works fine,

```
postgres=# SELECT count(*) FROM customer_reviews;
```

### count

589859
(1 row)

http://www.citusdata.com/downloads

Comment: did you get any solution for this? Now i am facing the same error. can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was using RazorSQL query tool using JDBC. But I change to ODBC and now is working.

Answer (score 2):

Citing from the [Common Errors](https://citusdata.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DOCS/Common+Errors#CommonErrors-ERROR:cannotexecutePREPAREforadistributedqueryplan) page on CitusDB's Wiki.

> The most common cause for this error is that tools using ODBC/JDBC drivers typically try to use a PREPARE statement by default, which is currently unsupported by CitusDB. This can very easily be resolved by downgrading the JDBC or ODBC protocol version to avoid using PREPARE statements.
>
> For ODBC drivers, depending on the particular driver/tool you are using there is sometimes an option to disable PREPARE statements. Alternatively, you could just revert the protocol to version 7.2 which is nearly always possible.
>
> For JDBC drivers, the exact steps depend a bit more on the particular driver. But, you can almost always set protocolVersion as 2 either in the driver properties or by specifying it in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

PgJDBC uses server-side prepared statements, and it looks like this "citusdb" tool does not support them.

Try [setting the prepare threshold](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/server-prepare.html), so PgJDBC won't try to prepare statements; see [`setPrepareThreshold`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGStatement.html#setPrepareThreshold%28int%29). If I recall correctly you can set it with `p repareThreshold=0` in the JDBC URL instead, though that'll then affect all connections.

Answer (score 1):

I am also got the same problem with CitusDB with JDBC integration, but there is a solution.

You have give the Protocol Version with connection string, like

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?protocolVersion=2");
```

Presently CitusDB JDBC works with Protocol Version 2 only.

I got the result, hope it will solve your problem.